# System.Speech in Silverlight is not offered

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, silverlight-5.0, speech-recognition

How can I use System.Speech in Silverlight (Out-of-browser) or Silverlight 5 (in-browser with elevated trust)?

I tried http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/nesl library but it [doesn't](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/nesl/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=4905) have dictation grammar, that's why I'm trying to use system.speech which has a dictation grammar.

Answer (score 0):

The [NeslSourceV2.zip](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/nesl) has a DictationLoad() method in it, so I would expect that dictation does work.